# Weblogic 10 embeddable EJB container

Tags: junit, automated-tests, weblogic, integration-testing, legacy-code

My task is to come with automated integration tests for a legacy EJB 2.1 code base that is running on Weblogic 10.1 server. Does anybody know if there is an emeddable container I can use in JUnit? I can see plenty of examples for Weblogic 12 , but not 10.

Any relevant suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with mockejb. It is working fine for my testcases. 
Just giving some sample.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mockejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockejb</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


private ServiceAccess bean;
private ServiceAccessHome home;


protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    MockServiceAccessBean mockServiceAccessbean = new MockServiceAccessBean();
    MockContextFactory.setAsInitial();
    MockContainer container = new MockContainer(new InitialContext());
    container.deploy(new SessionBeanDescriptor("ServiceAccess", ServiceAccessHome.class,
            ServiceAccess.class, mockServiceAccessbean));
    home = (ServiceAccessHome) new InitialContext().lookup("ServiceAccess");
    bean = home.create();

}

public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    MockContextFactory.revertSetAsInitial();
    bean.remove();
    super.tearDown();
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I'll give it a whirl.